# apache phpmyadmin setup for vhost

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, shared-hosting, php

I want to setup phpmyadmin for multi vhost users like.

```
example.tld_01/phpmyadmin
example.tld_02/phpmyadmin
```

**NOTE:** All apache vhost users and php script are chroot'ed for `/var/www/html/[web_dir]` through `PHP-FPM + mod_proxy_fcgi`

**Try 01 => symbolic link:**

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/* /var/www/html/[web_dir]/phpmyadmin
```

**Problem 01:**

```
Since php is chrooted users will not be able to access symbolic link of phpmyadmin
```

**Try 02 => mount --bind:**

```
mount --bind /usr/share/phpmyadmin/* /var/www/html/[web_dir]/phpmyadmin
```

**Problem 02:**

```
phpmyadmin has got some symbolic linked files in its libraries like "php-gettext/gettext.inc".
So getting this error.
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the best scenario in shared hosting to setup phpmyadmin for multi vhost and its users?
2. If you have used shared hosting, you wont see any folder like phpmyadmin in your account. But still you can access phpmyadmin. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

About your overall problem, have you thought about using TCP/IP networking instead of sockets?

About your problem 02, that must be how your distribution has chosen to package their version of phpMyAdmin -- the official phpMyAdmin source does not have a symlink as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html)

In this case for every VirtualHost you will be able to point to same directory like:

```
<Virtualhost tld1:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tld1/
  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</virtualHost>
<Virtualhost tld2:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tld2/
  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</virtualHost>
```

Should works good in your case. And it is an answer to both of your questions! :)